# Problem embedding youtube video's with with django template

Tags: django, iframe, youtube, x-frame-options

I have a django template that displays a list of objects with youtube videos:

```
{% for obj in objs %}
    <h1>{{ obj.name }}</h1>
    <iframe width="425" height="349" src="{{ obj.video}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
{% endfor %}
```

`obj.video` is stord as a urlField. When I load the page chrome console gives me the error `refused to display document because display forbidden by x-frame-options`.

The problem persists if I replace `{{ obj.video }}` with a manually written youtube embed url such as `http://youtu.be/zzfQwXEqYaI`.  However, if I replace it with something like `www.google.com` the iframes will load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try embedding the video like with url like:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/zzfQwXEqYaI
```

I guess its some kind of protection from youtube

Comment: well that does display them.  My only concern is that using the youtube api for submitting videos it's going to give me embed urls in the short form so I would have to parse the urls.  Is this a valid concern?

Comment: Well, I have never used the Youtube API - my answer was a wild guess (with a little testing before) - but I also guess the API should provide a way to return the url for embedding the video. If it doesn't, parsing the url seems perfectly legitimate :)